# How to send sensor data from Arduino UNO to MySQL database using SIM808GSM/GPRS shield

Tags: mysql, arduino-uno, gsm

I want to send sensor(SW-420 vibration module sensor) data from Arduino UNO to mysql database using SIM808 GSM/GPRS/GPS Shield (https://www.google.com/search?q=SIM808+gsm+shield&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi09rfhg6HVAhWFjpQKHZLJAIkQ_AUICigB&biw=1366&bih=672#imgrc=Bci2YDCfpzQlAM:). How can i do that?

Comment: What have you tried up until now? Where is your MySQL database installed? Have you successfully interacted with the database from any type of application of your own?

Comment: i have a domain and hosting named carsafe.xyz where my MySQL database installed. Yes, i have successfully interected the database with my officemanagement system application and blood bank management system but i didn't interect the database with any hardware application. I have study about GSM/GPRS shield but didn't find any usefull resource thats why i have no idea where to start. Can you please help me ?

Comment: please help me guys

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/ChuckBell/MySQL_Connector_Arduino and replace with your domain name and database settings in the given examples first to confirm you have proper setting.
For database(MYSQL or MariaDB) configuration, host should be "%" to allow external connection.